# Entity Framework can't revert a transaction, how to declare transactions inside a Procedure?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, transactions

Having a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tmpDelete
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Value DATE
)
GO
```

Then I declare my procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [TestSP]
    @prmDate DATE
AS
BEGIN
    --PRINT '@@TRANCOUNT : ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
    BEGIN TRANSACTION TestTransaction
    BEGIN TRY
        --PRINT '@@TRANCOUNT : ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
        INSERT INTO dbo.tmpDelete
                ( Value )
        VALUES  ( 'abc'  -- Value - date
                  );
        COMMIT TRANSACTION TestTransaction
        --PRINT '@@TRANCOUNT : ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TestTransaction
        DECLARE @NVERRO_MESS NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @INERR_SEVE INT, @INER_STAT INT;
        SELECT @NVERRO_MESS = ERROR_MESSAGE(), @INERR_SEVE = ERROR_SEVERITY(), @INER_STAT = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@NVERRO_MESS, @INERR_SEVE, @INER_STAT)
        --PRINT '@@TRANCOUNT : ' + CAST(@@TRANCOUNT AS NVARCHAR(10))
        RETURN
    END CATCH
END
GO
```

And when I call it from Entity Framework it returns the following error message:

> Cannot roll back TestTransaction.  No transaction or savepoint of that
>   name was found. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates that a
>   COMMIT or ROLLBACK TRANSACTION statement is missing. Previous count =
>   %1, current count = %2.

How should I declare my transactions?

Comment: Did you check if it works using ADO (without EF)?

Comment: Is this procedure called by another procedure that also creates a transaction? If that's the case, your `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION TestTransaction` will try to roll back the outermost transaction which may not be correct

Comment: In general, do you create any transaction before calling this procedure?

Comment: For more information about nesting transaction: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx .